# How to add different shape border?

Tags: css

Is it possible to echieve this kind of thing only using css?

[image: Border Image]

and html looks like:

```
<div class="blocks-wrapper">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

I found one kind of solution :

```
.blocks-wrapper {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));  
}
```

but this makes shodow not a border and I need something like border. I can add different classes every single block from javascript or use svg files but if this is possible to do without it it will be way less work and not heavy too. Thanks!

Comment: That design is certainly possible, though it's likely to be quite fragile. Is it just that shape you need, or should the user be able to do something in order to change it?

Comment: yess user must choose blocks and drag and drop, but this is another work, no ?

Comment: This is not a site to just get code written for you. We are here to help you with code you have written and have a specific problem with - but not to do your whole work for you.

Comment: That being said, you might want to look into the `box-shadow` property - with `inset` you can make that create the shadow _inside_ the box, so perhaps that could help you achieve those blue-ish, mushy parts inside the boxes (assuming those are actually part of what you want, and not some graphics glitch.)

Comment: @misorude :/ I thought I wrote good question :( I wrote my solution what I found and wanted to know if it is possible to do that, and if it is show me the way that's it. I don't ask to do my whole work and why I deserve -1 I don't got it : /

Comment: Well then please don’t comment with _“can you write solution if you know and have free time”_, because that makes it sound exactly as if you wanted others to do the whole work for you. Your current code only adds drop-shadow for the whole container element, doesn’t even apply it to individual boxes inside that container. You should start by creating an example that at least shows a couple of those boxes, with borders applied at the relevant sides of the relevant boxes, to get the basic blue shape from the image. If you provide that, we can go from there to add additional stuff like shadows etc

Comment: @misorude Thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this hope it will help:

```js
// DATA -----------

var points = [
  {"x" :  0 , "y" :  40},
  {"x" : 30 , "y" :  40},
  {"x" : 30 , "y" :  20},
  {"x" : 60 , "y" :  20},
  {"x" : 60 , "y" : -10},
  {"x" : 30 , "y" : -10},
  {"x" : 30 , "y" :   0},
  {"x" :  0 , "y" :   0},
  {"x" :  0 , "y" :  10},
  {"x" : -30, "y" :  10},
  {"x" : -30, "y" :  20},
  {"x" :   0, "y" :  20},
];

//-----------

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(c.width / 2, c.height / 2);
ctx.scale(1,-1);

// DRAW THE GRID ----------

ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle= "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)";
ctx.beginPath();

for (let i = 0; i < 200 ;i++) {

  ctx.moveTo(i*10,-200);
  ctx.lineTo(i*10,200);
  
  ctx.moveTo(-i*10,-200);
  ctx.lineTo(-i*10,200);
  
  ctx.moveTo(200, i*10);
  ctx.lineTo(-200, i*10);
  
  ctx.moveTo(200, -i*10);
  ctx.lineTo(-200, -i*10);
  
}

ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

// DRAW THE SHAPE ----------

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo((points[0].x),(points[0].y));
for (let i = 1; i < points.length ;i++) {
  ctx.lineTo((points[i].x), points[i].y);
}
ctx.closePath();

  
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle="white";
ctx.fill()
```

```css
.draw {
  border:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="draw"><canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas></div>
```

Comment: Thank you in advanced! Now I got it why I got -2 :/ . I mentioned that if I use different classes for blocks than yes I can do it, but I was trying to do without it. Imagine there is big data - from which I should drew this kind of blue blocks, If I loop it and add appropriate classes I can achieve that, but I was asking if it was possible to give some kind fo styles to "blocks-wrapper" and "block" classes and get result. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Okey !! at this point i think you should use canvas it's more flexible  you can draw shapes like you want [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Tutoriel_canvas/Formes_g%C3%A9om%C3%A9triques)

Comment: Yes, every block has its own (x,y). And thank you for advice!

Comment: @vano i edited the the answer using canvas , hope this will help

Comment: This looks really good, I am trying different solution right now, but if it doesn't work out I will do this. One question, though, imagine there is like 10 000 this kind of blocks, and you can drag and drop this block also combine or seperate and you can do 3-4 more different kind of actions too. Which way you think will be more light to render and for UX. I know probably you can't tell me 100% sure but, I just want to hear your opinion. Thanks !!!

Comment: Actually This is a solution, I forgot to accept your answer : )

Comment: @vano about your question i think canvas is more flexible and light weight to render because  it work on axis  and by default it offer diffrent events  like the **drag** , so you can edit, delete,  add ...   you will be free to manage your shape like you want and easily,  hope i answered the question clearly, and you are welcome ^_^ !!